# Want to measure entanglement of the state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, hilbert-space, measurement-problem

Good day,

I want to measure the state with concurrence and negativity.

I do local unitary transformation with represented by $U\in SU(4)$ (Lie group).

After the transformation (rotation of angle) of the pure state (as example $|00>$. Then, I  measure the new state (state after transform) with concurrence and negativity.

My question are:

1. to transform the state, it is compulsory to make the state |00> in density matrix before transform it? Or I can use directly the |00>.
2. To do the measurement towards the new state, which one the correct;

   a. $U\rho U^\dagger$ or

   b. $U\rho$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not required to put the state in density matrix form prior to performing the unitary operation $U$. However, you want to learn properties about the reduced density matrix after tracing out some of the system post-unitary, so you need a density matrix eventually. So you could do the unitary, and then construct the density matrix:
$$
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left| #1 \right\rangle}
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right|}
\ket{00} \to U \ket{00} \to U \ket{00} \bra{00} U^\dagger
$$
Or, you could construct the density matrix and then apply the unitary. Either way you get the same answer:
$$
\ket{00} \to \ket{00} \bra{00} \to U \ket{00} \bra{00} U^\dagger
$$
This should also answer your question 2: you need to apply the unitary to both sides of the density matrix (and I hope this reasoning also makes it clear why).